# Is there a way to do a Series.map in place, but keep original value if no match?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, optimization

The scenario here is that I've got a dataframe `df` with raw integer data, and a dict `map_array` which maps those ints to string values.

I need to **replace the values in the dataframe with the corresponding values from the map, but keep the original value if the it doesn't map to anything.**

So far, the only way I've been able to figure out how to do what I want is by using a temporary column.  However, with the size of data that I'm working with, this could sometimes get a little bit hairy. And so, I was wondering if there was some trick to do this in pandas without  needing the temp column...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5, size=(100,1)))
map_array = {1:'one', 2:'two', 4:'four'}

df['__temp__'] = df[0].map(map_array, na_action=None) 
#I've tried varying the na_action arg to no effect

nan_index = data['__temp__'][df['__temp__'].isnull() == True].index
df['__temp__'].ix[nan_index] = df[0].ix[nan_index]
df[0] = df['__temp__']
df = df.drop(['__temp__'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can simply use `.replace`, whether on a `DataFrame` or a `Series`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5, size=(3,3)))
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  3  4  3
1  2  1  2
2  4  2  3
>>> map_array = {1:'one', 2:'two', 4:'four'}
>>> df.replace(map_array)
      0     1    2
0     3  four    3
1   two   one  two
2  four   two    3
>>> df.replace(map_array, inplace=True)
>>> df
      0     1    2
0     3  four    3
1   two   one  two
2  four   two    3
```

I'm not sure what the memory hit of changing column dtypes will be, though.

Comment: thanks.  the hit for changing column types is one that i need to take anyway, so that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

`map` (or `applymap` for a dataframe) seems faster.

The trick is to use `lambda x: mapping.get(x, x)` as the mapping, essentially returning the value unchanged by default.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(100, 1000)))

mapping = {1: "one", 2: "two", 4: "four"}

res1 = df.replace(mapping)
res2 = df.applymap(lambda x: mapping.get(x, x))

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(res1, res2)
```

```
>>> %timeit df.replace(mapping)
>>> %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: mapping.get(x, x))
175 ms ± 855 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
86.1 ms ± 725 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```